# MySQL command line formatting with UTF8

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a database table that contains Swedish/Norwegian strings.

When I query some data, I get output like this:

### Output with `set names latin1;`

```
+-----------------------------------+
| name                              |
+-----------------------------------+
| Kid Interi#####                   | 
| Bwg Homes                         | 
| If Skadef####kring                | 
| Jangaard Export                   | 
| Nordisk Film                      | 
+-----------------------------------+
```

Now if I `set names utf8;` in order to see the characters with their proper encoding, then the formatting of the tabular output of the MySQL command line breaks.

### Output with `set names utf8;`

```
+-----------------------------------+
| name                              |
+-----------------------------------+
| Kid Interiør                     | 
| Bwg Homes                         | 
| If Skadeförsäkring              | 
| Jangaard Export                   | 
| Nordisk Film                      | 
+-----------------------------------+
```

### Question:

This is not a big issue but it makes the output a bit harder to read. Does anybody know how to keep the tabular formatting intact?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

#### Short answer

Start the client with option `--default-character-set=utf8`:

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8
```

You can set this as a default in the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file.

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

#### The short answer did not work, read below

The command above forces the `character_set_client`, `character_set_connection` and `character_set_results` config variables to be `utf8`.

In order to check the values for all the charset related config variables you can run:

```
show variables like '%char%';
```

The `character_set_database` gives you the character set of the current database (schema) that you are in. The schema and tables are created by default with the charset specified in the `character_set_server`, unless it is specified explicitly in the `CREATE` statement.

The `character_set_server` can be changed in the `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
```

Additionally, tables and columns can have their own charset which might be different from their parent table or schema. To specifically check the values of each table and column in a database see this answer:
[How do I see what character set a MySQL database / table / column is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is/1049958#1049958)

If you want to change the character set of existing tables and columns, see this answer: [How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8/6115705#6115705)

More info on connection character sets in the [mysql docsumentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html).

#### Everything is set to utf8, but I still see weird characters

Even if all the charsets variables, tables and columns are set to `utf8`, there might be cases where you see weird characters on your screen. For example, somebody might have written Unicode characters in a `utf8` column, through a client with `latin1` connection (for example by running `mysql --default-character-set=latin1`). In this case you need to connect to the database with the same charset as the values were written. You can also retrieve and rewrite them through the correct encoding.

**NOTE**: As the comments point out, the mysql `utf8` encoding is not a true and full implementation of UTF-8. If a full implementation of UTF-8 is needed, one can use the `utf8mb4` charset:

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

More info here: [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql)

Comment: This did help indeed. So starting mysql command line like this does the trick `mysql --default-character-set=utf8`

Comment: I'm not sure that the statement "This [--default-character-set=utf8] forces the character_set_client, character_set_connection and character_set_results variables to be UTF8. " is right, because mysql has also got the utf8mb4 charset, which is their true implementation of UTF8. mysql's utf8 uses only 3 bytes, leaving out a range of characters of the UTF8 table

Comment: well it forces them to be utf8, whatever utf8 means in mysql. I have changed it to lowercase so there is no confusion.

Comment: @reallynice The distinction is a fine one, and valid. If the full 4-byte implementation is needed then the utf8mb4 can be used on the command line; `mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4`

Answer (score -2):

These words "ø ö ä" with utf8 takes 2 bytes, so did you forget use wchar or utf string?

Here's my test code in python:

```
s = ["Kid Interiør","Bwg Homes","If Skadeförsäkring"]
for w in s:
    print '|',w.ljust(20,' '),'|'
```

the result is as the same as your program print out.
all I need to do is change the encoding of string `s`:

```
s = [u"Kid Interiør",u"Bwg Homes",u"If Skadeförsäkring"]
for w in s:
    print '|',w.ljust(20,' '),'|'
```

the result is

```
| Kid Interiør         |
| Bwg Homes            |
| If Skadeförsäkring   |
```

I haven't test in c++, but I suggest you can use wchar, std::wcout.

Comment: The OP is asking how to configure `mysql-client`.