# General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xAE\x95\xE0\xAF\x8A...' for column 'occupation' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, utf-8, laravel-5.4

I am doing Tamil Language based Billing Web Application in Laravel. When I store tamil Unicode Data in database its display following Error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xAE\x95\xE0\xAF\x8A...' for column 'occupation' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `occupation` (`occupation`, `created_by`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (கொத்தனார், 1, 2017-06-07 10:14:58, 2017-06-07 10:14:58))
```

How to Fix this Issue. I change db config to

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

and also defined charset to utf-8 in page Head

[image]

Comment: make sure the table collation is utf8 too

Comment: @Onix already i set Table Collation to utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788223/4668162 i hope it works,

Comment: @Onix Finally i change occupation data type to blob its inserted. blob data type is good for storing unicode characters