# mycli - can't not show unicode message

Tags: mysql, dbclient

I'm meeting a problem with show message UNICODE on console with mycli (with image attachment). Please help me how to config mycli to show message unicode beautiful.

I was researched all source but can't config.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/18625823/56551471-ac407400-65b2-11e9-8d1b-e26aeea269b6.png

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787824/mysql-command-line-formatting-with-utf8

Comment: Check the default character set, and according set it to your requirement. UTF-8 should be the default one in general!