# '?' instead of persian character

Tags: cmd, farsi

I am tried to work with 'MySQL'.
but when I want to write in Persian keyboard, it doesn't show correctly

how can I fix this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RytvA.png)

its preview

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787824) should help you. Be sure to read the initial question, to understand your problem better, and then move on to the accepted answer.

Comment: use utf8 charset and collation for database or table or column.